# Is it possible to have a flex div take the height of its outer container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For example, in the fiddle below, I have a single flex div.

It appears that setting the height to 100% has no effect on the div.

A div is display block by default and takes up 100% of the width.  But obviously the height behaves differently.

https://jsfiddle.net/02wtuzjp/1/

```css
#expand{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'expand'>
</div>
```

This appears to be expected behavior as there is not content in the div.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/height/

One solution is to use the units `vh` or more particularly `100vh`.

I'm not sure it this is the proper or best way, however.

Comment: The problem is your use of percentage heights. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin thanks for finding the dupe! I was looking for that before I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

An element with a percentage based height, needs a [parent reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height#values) for it to base its height on. You can add:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And your element will be 100% of the height:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#expand {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="expand">
</div>
```

Per your edit:
You can certainly use `100vh` to set the height, but then that element will always be 100 percent of the height of the viewport..no matter it's containing element.

For example:

```css
#random {
  height: 50px;
}

#expand {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="random">
</div>
<div id="expand">
</div>
```

You can see that the height of your `expand` element is 100vh tall and creates a scroll because the height is the height of viewport, not the remaining space.

Resources:
[Article on Medium](https://medium.com/fink-it/why-is-height-not-working-242cb7167940)

Comment: That is cool, I posted a link by css-tricks, which just confused me more obviously.  Can you relate your answer to the link I posted in the Q edit.

Comment: I've noticed this behavior while developing but have not seen it referenced anywhere.  Can you provide a web reference - mdn, stack overflow, etc.

Comment: @user17331023 the link to the `parent reference` in my answer is the MDN. If you read under the `<percentage>` heading you'll see that it talks about the `containing element`. I know there's more info out there. I'll add it.